# JAR file Error when open it

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have exported JAR file from Java Eclipse application and its work correctly. 
this what show when export :

[image]

This JAR doesn't work correctly. it returns the error below:

[image]

there is my main class :

```
package testJarFileProject;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class testJarFileProject {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
            "my application", 
            "show", 
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
            (Integer) 0, 
            null, 
            new String[]{"ok"}, 
            "default");

   }

  }
```

what is the problem ? is exporting jar file is not correct while it doesn't give me an error ?
any help 
thank you

Comment: Could you post some code? And I'm betting you don't have a main method...

Comment: A jar file is different from an **executable** jar file.

Comment: Are you trying to _open_ (unpack) the jar file, or are you trying to _use_ the jar file by putting it on the classpath and invoking a class from it, or are you trying to run its default class using the `java -jar` syntax? If the latter, you need to explicitly say which class should be used as the main class when you build the jar.

Comment: is the version of java cause this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

You should understand what happen when you  "open" your jar. I believe that you mean that you perform double click on it.

If my assumption is correct your jar is "executed", i.e. command line like the following is executed: `java -jar yourjar.jar`.

What is really happening in this case? JVM opens your jar and tries to access file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` that should contain line like the following:

`Main-Class: com.company.MyClass`

JVM extracts the fully qualified class name and try to perform action that is equivalent to:

`java -cp yourjar.jar com.company.MyClass`

If class `com.company.MyClass` cannot be found in jar the error message like one that you sent will be printed.

Now you have all tools to discover your problem. First, try to run your program using command like the `java -cp yourjar.jar com.company.MyClass`. If error remains check the jar: it does not have the main class. If problem disappears check your manifest. It contains mistake.

If everything looks OK, check compatibility of versions of your compiler and JVM. Probably you compiled your code using compiler of higher version than the JVM you are using to run your program.

Good luck.

Comment: i have the META-INF folder all the requirement is done and correct , does the problem in version of java i installed in my desktop ?

Comment: It is probably the problem. Check your java version using `java -version`. Check your compiler version too. As far as I understand you compiled your code using IDE, so check its preferences.